# Compare time in updated_at and Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I'm using Rails 3 and want to get all rows that is updated in the last 30 minutes.

This is my current code:

```
Post.find(:all, condition: { updated_at: Time.now..Time.now-30.minutes })
```

**But it returns every single rows**, I also have tried this:

```
Post.find(:all, condition: [
  "updated_at between ? AND ?", Time.now, Time.now - 30.minutes
])
```

It still return all rows.

I think the problem lies in the **format** difference.

`updated_at` format is like `2014-01-26T17:22:52+08:00`

While `Time.now` format is like `2014-02-10 14:39:40 +0800`

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Post.where('updated_at > ?', 30.minutes.ago)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect that method exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
Post.where('updated_at > ?', Time.now - 30.minutes )
```